# C pointer only using 24 bits

Tags: c, linux, pointers

I have following snippet where value of pointer is printed, since it is pointer, on 64 bit machine, its size is 8 bytes, and 64 bits should be used to represent the address, But:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char *s = "";
   printf("%p %p\n", s, (char*)(int)s);
   return 0;
}
```

But output is :

0x4005e4 0x4005e4

why only 24 bits are used for the pointer value, shouldn't this be 64 bits ?

Also, is it UB if cast of different size pointer are involved like here (char *)(int)s ?

What I was expecting with this (char)s to give only 1 Byte address but it is printing 8 bytes address?

Comment: The address `0x4005e4` is really the same as `0x00000000004005e4`. So it's still 64 bits, just that the upper bits happen to be zero.

Comment: Leading zero suppression. Like I have 1 cent, not 01 (100 in a dollar).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, Weather Vane, got the point, also I have updated the question to put up follow-up queries, Kindly have a look.

Comment: You cast it to `char*` (a pointer, so 64 bits), not to `char` (8 bits).

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes,  (char)s is another example apart from (char *)(int)s. is there a format specifier to just print pointer value of 1 Byte ?

Comment: The size of a pointer is fixed. There are no "one byte pointers". A pointer could *point* to a single byte (that's generally what a `char *` is doing) but the size of the pointer is not related to the size of the data being pointed to.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: The C standard permits pointers to different types to have different sizes and representations, with some restrictions, and there are C implementations in which pointers of different types have different sizes.

Comment: @EricPostpischil True, maybe should have added a "on a modern PC-like system" disclaimer. The chances of the OP ever coming across a system with differing pointer sizes are slim to none. :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, But isn't the typecaste thing doing the same, I mean pointer value is not going to be 64 bits anymore with (char)S or (int)S ?

Comment: sizeof((char )s) is 1 byte now.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is specified to *always* be `1`, no matter its actual bit-width. Regarding the casts, if you cast to a non-pointer type you  might loose bits. Like `(char) s` will truncate to eight bits (assuming the common 8-bit `char`). But then if you cast back to a pointer (e.g. `(char *) (char) s`) you still have a pointer with the full size of the pointer (64 bits on a normal 64-bit PC system).

Comment: To print a pointer with `%p` just cast it to `(void*)`. Do not – *I repeat: __DO NOT__* – cast it through any other type as this might truncate it. (Casting through `uintptr_t` is safe, but why'd you do this in the first place, if `%p` expects a `void*`?)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you keep saying "a 1 byte address" or "pointer value of 1 byte".  If you cast a pointer to `char`, you get an implementation-defined small integer in the range of `char`, most likely the low 8 bits of the pointer (possibly sign-extended).  That integer is not the address of anything.  If you cast it back to a pointer, you get some implementation-defined value that does not point to anything and will likely cause undefined behavior if you dereference it.

Comment: @NateEldredge, I think when we cast it to (char *) the pointer address would not change, its just only 1 Byte of that address can be accessed but when we type caste it to say (char ) or (int ) then its completely different address all together, in fact some thing invalid, is this right understanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why only 24 bits are used for the pointer value

Your pointers happen to have their most significant bits set to zero, so they aren't printed.  If you really want to print all 64 bits, you can change your printf format string to make it print leading zeros.

> is it UB if cast of different size pointer are involved like here (char *)(int)s ?

There are no "different size pointers" on the machines you're likely to be using, but `int` is commonly 32 bits.  So by casting through `int` on the way to `char*`, you are throwing away the most significant 32 bits.  If they were zero, you may not notice the difference, but if not you'll corrupt the pointer and nobody knows what you'll get if you dereference it.  You can still print its value (i.e. the address it points to, even if it's nonsense).

Comment: But typecasting like this (char)s , should have trimmed of 56 bits from 64 bit address value, no ?

Comment: `(char)` would trim 56 bits, but the code in the question used `(char*)` which is a 64 bit pointer not an 8 bit character.

Comment: Re “There are no "different size pointers," ”: The C standard permits pointers to different types to have different sizes and representations, with some restrictions, and there are C implementations in which pointers of different types have different sizes.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I've added the required weasel words to that part of my answer in case OP is running on a 64-bit machine from the 1970s.